# Expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 302 in requests test in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I found lots of similar questions posted by others but none of the solutions worked.

My /spec/requests/questions_spec.rb is

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Questions", type: :request do
  describe "GET /questions" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      get questions_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Now my rspec error

```
Questions GET /questions works! (now write some real specs)
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
   expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 302
 # ./spec/requests/questions_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone help me? How do I customize my code to get the status code 200 ?

Comment: 200 is a success, 302 is found. Rails scaffold return 302 on get method.

Comment: Can you please share you controller code here?

Comment: maybe you have an authentication in your app that's why the request returns 302

Comment: Are you using authentication for this controller? @Sridhar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`302 - Found`. I think you are using rails scaffold. Scaffold syntax return 302 status on get method. If you need 200. Youcan customize your code.

Comment: Thanks Velu Dhanesh. How do I customize the status code to 200?

Comment: Change your response like `render json: {data: 'your variable', status: 200, message: 'success'}`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing authentication.

use `login_user`

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec)

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue something like `expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302` When I did right this code

describe "GET #index" do

```
  it "returns http success" do
    get :index
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

You know what: I did not use `devise` gem so I could not use `login_user` and unfortunately I have forgotten how to implement the login without `devise`. It somehow kept login state using `session`. So I did something like this and it worked:

describe "GET #index" do

```
  it "returns http success" do

      admin = User.create(name:  "admin@gmail.com",
           email: "admin@gmail.com",
           password:              "admin@gmail.com",
           password_confirmation: "admin@gmail.com",
           admin:     true,
           activated: true,
           activated_at: Time.zone.now)

      session[:user_id] = admin.id

    get :index
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very likely using scaffold-generated methods as mentioned by @Velusamy Venkatraman and @Raj. So, you need to `sign_in` if you want to get 2xx status which means complete success. The 302 status means page exists but you were redirected (mostly in case of some error).

Do the following to solve the issue:

**Step 1:**
You can create custom methods like following in spec folder and then simply use them:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user, admin:true)
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

**Step 2:**

Add `login_user` or `login_admin` to your spec file wherever you need and change

`let(:valid_session) { {} }`

to

`let(:valid_session) { {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]} }`

I hope you are using `devise` and `warden` which are really useful if you don't want to worry about session/login/signup issues.

You can see their documentations here:
[plataformatec/devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
[wardencommunity/warden](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden)

This answer was written based on documentation of devise:
[devise-wiki-how-to-test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec))