# Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(200) rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

i always get 302 redirect after sign_in user with in sessions request test

```
Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(200)
     
       expected: 200
            got: 302
```

spec/requests/sessions_spec.rb

```
  describe do
   let!(:user) { create(:user) }

    context do
      before { sign_in user }

      it do
        get api_users_path
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
```

config:  spec_helper.rb

```
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :request
```

Comment: did you use `scaffold` ? scaffold syntax return 302 status on get method, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036873/expected-the-response-to-have-status-code-200-but-it-was-302-in-requests-test-in)

Comment: nope, not scaffold

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: ```devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is by providing Token in headers

```
request.headers['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/json'
request.headers['Authorization'] = token
```

and removing sign_in